# Postgres Remote Connection Timeout

Tags: iptables, redhat, postgresql, remote-access

I've been reading tutorials extensively to help figure out my problem, but to no avail.

I have a Redhat VM that I've installed Postgres on that I'm trying to make available for remote connections.  When I'm on the machine, if I run the following command, I am able to connect to my desired table.

```
psql -U philhouse -d pwap
```

However, when I try running this:

```
psql -U philhouse -d pwap -h servername.nu.edu
```

I always time out.

I've read multiple tutorials and guides, but still cannot figure it out. I've edited pg_hba.conf file, my postgres.conf file, as well as *attempted* to work with iptables.  Here are the outputs of the following just so that you can see:

**pg_hba.conf** I've changed to allow all connections for testing purposes

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

**postgres.conf** - here I changed listen_addresses to * just for testing purposes

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = '*'         # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                                        # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                            # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per 
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directory = ''             # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                        # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                        # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min          # 1s-600s
#ssl = off                              # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH'      # allowed SSL ciphers
                                        # (change requires restart)
#ssl_renegotiation_limit = 512MB        # amount of data between renegotiations
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off
```

** iptables ** I just attempted this .. not 100% sure what to do here.

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:NETBKP - [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 13720,13721,13782,13724,13783,13722,13723 -j NETBKP
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
#-A INPUT -s 129.105.214.0/255.255.255.0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
#-A INPUT -s 129.105.106.0/255.255.255.128 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
#-A INPUT -s 165.124.200.32/255.255.255.240 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 129.105.106.0/255.255.255.128 -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
#
#FP 121688
-A INPUT -s 129.105.0.0/255.255.0.0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 165.124.0.0/255.255.0.0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
#
#
#-A INPUT -s 129.105.119.86 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A NETBKP -s 129.105.106.0/255.255.255.128 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -s 129.105.208.18 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -s 129.105.208.20 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -s 129.105.208.82 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -s 129.105.208.115 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -s 129.105.208.116 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -s 129.105.215.131 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -s 165.124.61.0/255.255.255.128 -j ACCEPT
-A NETBKP -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
#-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j LOG
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Any thoughts or things that I'm missing? I've been working on this for 3 days and haven't made a bit of progress...

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you show the output of a 'netstat -tulpn' ?

Answer (score 0):

Set your listen_address appropriately (i.e. remove the comment character in front of the listen_address that's already there). By default postgres only listens to the local socket and localhost (loopback interface).

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you the whole process, please recheck step by step:

1. Add the following line into `'/etc/postgres/10/main/postgres.conf'`:

   ```
   listen_addresses = '*'
   ```
2. Add the following lines into `'/etc/postgres/10/main/pg_hba.conf'`:

   ```
   host  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  md5
   host  replication  all  0.0.0.0/0 md5
   ```
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
   ```